# Command Line Server?? Client Server Architecture?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, command-line, client-server

Hope are doing great.

here i do want to know about command line server, how can i access remotely command line server

via iPhone.

any thought any advise much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am doing well.  There are too many ways to mention.  All servers programs are run from the command line at some point and there are any number of transports and protocols you could use.  I suggest you have a service running which listens to TCP or UCP, sending text or binary in a one of the many standard formats, or one of your own.  It could run the command you need as required or have it embedded in your service.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Thanks peter basically my question is [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206548/accessing-java-library-over-server-client-server-architecture)   can you enlighten this..

Comment: Not without more details.  There is no standard way to do this.  If you are doing this on the Internet you cannot avoid security concerns and only you know what your security requirements are.  It is like asking, "I want to know how to write a program which uses a network"

Comment: Well i figured it out how to access command line server of java The problem is that when you close terminal or command programs the Java server shut down as well what i want to execute it in background, i heard about daemon  for doing that job, do we have multiple option for that or only daemon? what is the best choice.

Comment: You should post this as an answer because I haven't heard of a "command line server of java" before.

Comment: If you start a program from the command line and you close it, it sends a HUP signal to all of it's child processes.  The way to avoid this killing your process is to use `nohup` at the start of you command line.  This blocks the signal and prevents your process being killed when you exit.  This is true of all UNIX programs and not specific to Java at all.

Comment: I mean to access  Java library that act as server via terminal that are listening at some port say 2050, Does that make sense ??

Comment: I think I know what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Lawrey guided me in right direction above in the comments. For others if they are looking for answer to the question i asked here on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) 
"**If you start a program from the command line and you close it, it sends a HUP signal to all of it's child processes. The way to avoid this killing your process is to use nohup at the start of you command line. This blocks the signal and prevents your process being killed when you exit. This is true of all UNIX programs and not specific to Java at all.**"